# how to show multiple row data in one row for all unique ids

Tags: mysql

I have below query which select languages of different source but I want to show it in one row

```
    SELECT msg_id,
    CASE WHEN source=0 THEN language_name END AS 'language1',
    CASE WHEN source=2 THEN language_name END AS 'language2',
    CASE WHEN source=1 THEN language_name END AS 'language3'
    FROM languages 
     WHERE msg_id=90491


    msg_id  language1   language2   language3
    90491    Marathi     NULL        NULL
    90491    NULL        NULL        English
    90491    NULL        Hindi        NULL
```

but I want result as

```
   msg_id   language1   language2   language3
    90491    Marathi     Hindi       English
```

how do i get it

Comment: please post the schema of language table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INNER` select queries, e.g.:

```
SELECT l.msg_id,
 (SELECT language_name FROM languages WHERE msg_id = l.msg_id AND source = 0) AS 'language1',
 (SELECT language_name FROM languages WHERE msg_id = l.msg_id AND source = 1) AS 'language2',
 (SELECT language_name FROM languages WHERE msg_id = l.msg_id AND source = 2) AS 'language3'
FROM languages l
WHERE l.msg_id=90491
```

This query assumes there's only one record per `msg_id` and `source` combination in the table.

Comment: in my table, there are multiple rows of one msg having diff sources 0,1 and 2

Comment: this query gives me error like multiple rows selected by subquery

Comment: but i want to know why here you used like WHERE msg_id = l.msg_id

Comment: Because it needs to fetch the corresponding `language_name` for a message being returned by outer query (with `l` table alias)